# No such task (cider) when cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, spacemacs, cider

When trying to `cider-jack-in` in Spacemacs I am getting the following error message: `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such task (cider)`

Here is the full stack trace.

```
[nREPL] Starting server via /home/bob/.linuxbrew/bin/boot -i "(require 'cider.tasks)" -d org.clojure/tools.nrepl\:0.2.13 -d com.billpiel/sayid\:0.0.16 -d refactor-nrepl\:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT -d cider/cider-nrepl\:0.18.0-SNAPSHOT cider.tasks/add-middleware -m com.billpiel.sayid.nrepl-middleware/wrap-sayid -m refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor -m cider.nrepl/cider-middleware cider repl -s wait...
error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Classpath conflict: org.clojure/clojure version 1.9.0 already loaded, NOT loading version 1.2.0
                              java.lang.Thread.run              Thread.java:  748
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  624
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker  ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1149
               java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run          FutureTask.java:  266
                                               ...                               
               clojure.core/binding-conveyor-fn/fn                 core.clj: 2022
                                 boot.core/boot/fn                 core.clj: 1032
                                               ...                               
                         boot.core/construct-tasks                 core.clj:  986
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such task (cider)
        clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such task (cider)
```

Answer (score 1):

I seems that my `~/.boot/profile.boot` file was containing outdated content. I replaced it with the following:

```
(deftask cider "CIDER profile"
  []
  (require 'boot.repl)
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/*default-dependencies*)
         concat '[[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.15.0"]
                  [refactor-nrepl "2.3.1"]])
  (swap! @(resolve 'boot.repl/*default-middleware*)
         concat '[cider.nrepl/cider-middleware
                  refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor])
  identity)
```